Improving Intellisense depth for a project in VSCode
I know how I can increase package index depth for to improve other packages in  Intellisense in VSCode, but I don't know how to increase Intellisense depth for my own project in VSCode.
For improving other packages, Intellisense. I go to the settings.json file for the current project and add this for:
"python.analysis.packageIndexDepths": [
        {
            "name": "third_party_package_name_1", // The name of the third party package that I intend to improve its performance by increasing the depth of the index
            "depth": 5   // index depth for improving intellisense
        },{
            "name": "third_party_package_name_1",
            "depth": 5
        }
    ]

I tried to write my project folder name instead of package_name but it didn't work. But when I wrote name of third party packages, it worked perfectly.

if you are trying to optimize the quality of IntelliSense. You can configure the vscode file settings.json file. Add "python.analysis.extraPaths":["yourpath"] to add the location. Then set "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode" to strict. Try to see if this solves the problem.
